# Not sure why my navbar-brand is stuck at the left side of the screen. Tried using ml-5. (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

I have tried using ml-5 and various other spacers. This is for bootstrap 5

```
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Signup.html">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. There's padding by default.

Answer (score 1):

for bootstrap 5 u have to use ms-5 not ml-5 or in this case ps-5

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark ps-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="Signup.html">Sign In</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add container class to the navbar like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Wrapped with container-fluid -->
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Wrapped with collapse navbar-collapse, otherwise navs won't be visible -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Signup.html">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Wrapped with collapse navbar-collapse, otherwise navs won't be visible -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Wrapped with container-fluid -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Add container-fluid inside the navbar
2. Wrap navs with collapse navbar-collapse

Source - > https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/